# How do I override component style written with SCSS in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, overriding

I'm new to `React` and `scss`. Maybe it's a basic question, but I think it's really strange.

I created 4 files :

Component.js

```
import React from "react";
import CompStyles from "./component.module.scss";

const Component = (props) => {
  console.log(CompStyles["test"], props.className);
  return (
    <div className={`${CompStyles["test"]} ${props.className}`}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Component;
```

component.module.scss

```
.test {
  color: red;
}
```

Demo.js

```
import React from "react";
import DemoStyles from "./demo.module.scss";
import Component from "./Component";

const Demo = (props) => {
  return <Component className={DemoStyles["demo"]}>Text</Component>;
};

export default Demo;
```

demo.module.scss

```
.demo {
  color: green;
}
```

`Component.js` is a basic component as its name show. And I include `Component` as a child of `Demo` in `Demo.js`. Both of them has their `scss` files.

My intention is obvious. I want to overwrite some styles of `Component`, so pass a `className` props to `Component` and process this logic in `Component.js`. But the result is that I can't overwrite it.

After some research and google, I know the reason that it's a `scss import priority` issue. When run `Demo.js`, `demo.module.scss` is loading, and `component.module.scss` will be loaded later.

So how do I achieve to override component styles ? I think it's a very basic requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just import **demo.module.scss** after **./Component**  in **Demo.js**, so that webpack will add **demo.module.scss** after **component.module.scss** in complied file.

Refer blow for import order in **Demo.js** .

```
import React from "react";
import Component from "./Component";
import DemoStyles from "./demo.module.scss";
```